Renovate App in GitHub with internal package as dependency
I have two internal repositories where repo A contains a helm chart, and in its values.yaml file it contains a dependency to an image which is build and published in the other internal repo B:
# in values.yaml in repo A
image:
  repository: org/repo
  tag: 0.1.0
  registry: ghcr.io

The Renovate configuration is:
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:recommended"
  ],
  "hostRules": [
    {
      "hostType": "docker",
      "matchHost": "ghcr.io",
      "encrypted": {
        "token": "<encryptedtoken>"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I created a PAT with repo rights and packages:read rights and encrypted it via the Mend page. However, I see that this PAT was never used and I still get the warning in the depedency dashboard in repo A:

Renovate failed to look up the following dependencies: Failed to look up docker package ghcr.io/org/repo.
Files affected: values.yaml


It seems like you need to change "token" to "password".
relevant discussion: https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/28319
Final config
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:recommended"
  ],
  "hostRules": [
    {
      "hostType": "docker",
      "matchHost": "ghcr.io",
      "encrypted": {
        "password": "<encryptedtoken>"
      }
    }
  ]
}

